# ASPNET MVC RenderAction with javascript parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do I pass javascript variable into MVC RenderAction parameter?

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GeneratePlayersSelect", new { teamid = ??? ] });}
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant. Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the client (javascript is client code so its not even in scope)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do it. Just have a id assigned to your Action and set href property again in JavaScript, like this:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GeneratePlayersSelect", "your_controller", new { id= "lnkPlayer" });}
```

And in JavaScript (after document loads), change the href:

```
document.getElementById('lnkPlayer').href = document.getElementById('lnkPlayer').href + '?teamid='+ yourVariable;
```

Which will change to `'your_controller/GeneratePlayersSelect?teamid=1'`

Hope it works, thank you.